# How to test LOCALLY an rails application layout on IE7 and IE8 from an MacOSX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, internet-explorer, virtualbox, webrick

So, I'm developing my rails applications on my mac, thro WEBrick at 0.0.0.0:3000 and I need to test how the layout are showing on PC running Windows with Internet Explorer 7 and IE8.

I have tried to test it thro Wine + Wine Bottler, but I can't access that point.

And now I'm thinking to install VirtualBox to give a try, but before doing this, it will be good to know from others if it will or not work for me in this case.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use VirtualBox for interface testing. I've had no problems with it at all. I have an external drive with various disk images for firing up various versions of Windows and thus various versions of IE as well as Firefox and Chrome. Works a treat and no complaints.

Comment: I've installed VirtualBox and Win7 but the rails application isn't accessible on the Virtual Machine thro WEBrick running at 0.0.0.0:3000 at least.

Comment: Ah yeah, I have to access it at: 10.0.2.2:3000. Does that work?

Comment: Nope, probably you have configured that IP address in another place. Do you know where?

Comment: Typing `ifconfig` at console I could see an different IP, I tried and it works! ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have used VirtualBox and a program called IETester:

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

It works well, even for IE6 although there are some very minor differences for IE6.

Makes it very quick to test in all versions of IE as you can have a tab for each.

Give it a go.

Comment: The rails application isn't accessible on the Virtual Machine. Any idea?

Comment: ifconfig then look use the ip address of your mac

Comment: I would really try out the IETester... you should not just test your site works in IE10 or whatever they are up to now... the deferences are vast in how they render and deal with js, especially between IE7 and up... this tool really helps

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look on IETester also ;)